# Query on populated field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently, I have two schemas:

```
var person = new schema({
id: Number,
name: String,
city: {
    type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'cities'
}
});
```

AND

```
var city = new schema({
id: Number,
name: String,
country: String,
country_short: String
});
```

And I have two models:

```
var persons = mongoose.model('persons', person);
var cities = mongoose.model('cities', city);
```

All working good. I can select a person and make it return `city` object on the spot of the `city`, perfect!

**The problem:**

I want to select all persons with a city that has the country_short "NL". I tried this:

```
persons.find({
  'city.country_short': 'NL'
}).populate('city').exec(function(err, data) {
  //Data SHOULD obtain all persons living in a city with country_short "NL".
});
```

This doesn't work. I found a solution that works but it's nested.. I don't like it. It selects all cities with country_short 'NL' and maps them. Then WITHIN that find (nested...) I find all persons and checking for city $in mapped array.

Help me with a NON NESTED solution. Or maybe an other way of doing this.

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To include query conditions with the referenced schema on **[populating](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)**, use the following approach:

```
persons.find(...)
       .populate({
           path: 'city',
           match: { country_short: 'NL'},
           select: 'name -_id', /* limit fields to return */
           options: { limit: 5 } /* limit documents to return */
       })
       .exec(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does not work. I still get ALL people, the ones without a city that has NL return "city: null".